# How to use IWorkspaceName2

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, vb.net

I'm trying to make a little utility to generate encrypted passwords for MSD files (change the XML inside the zip). I found this example online, but I'm not familiar with esri's API, so I'm not sure how to use `IWorkspaceName2::ConnectionString` as suggested in the following documentation link -

http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeodatabase/IWorkspaceFactory2_Example.htm

`OpenFromString` actually makes a connection, which is not ideal for my purposes, so if that can be ommited entirely and get the `ConnectionString` property value from the `IWorkspaceName2` that would do it. I wasn't able to find out how to create a `IWorkspaceName2` object so that's what I'm looking for, either c# or vb.net.

```
string connectionString = "SERVER=myServer;DATABASE=sde;INSTANCE=5151;USER=Editor;PASSWORD=Editor;VERSION=SDE.DEFAULT"
IWorkspaceFactory2 workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory2)new ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactoryClass();
return workspaceFactory.OpenFromString(connectionString, 0);

//A better solution is to use IWorkspaceName2::ConnectionString which returns an encrypted password:
ENCRYPTED_PASSWORD=0001d2756fc3e1b91529;SERVER=myServer;INSTANCE=5151;USER=Editor;VERSION=SDE.DEFAULT`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works with this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;

namespace SDEtest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.BindLicense(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.EngineOrDesktop);
            string connStr = "SERVER=server;INSTANCE=5151;VERSION=version;USER=user;PASSWORD=pwd";
            Console.WriteLine(GetConnStr(connStr));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static string GetConnStr(string ConnectionString)
        {
            Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory");
            IWorkspaceFactory2 workspaceFactory2 = (IWorkspaceFactory2)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
            IWorkspace ws = workspaceFactory2.OpenFromString(ConnectionString, 0);

            IDataset dataset = (IDataset)ws;

            IWorkspaceName2 name2 = (IWorkspaceName2)dataset.FullName;

            return name2.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
}
```